# Scala sequence concatenation

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following code:

```
  def getLists(token: String, username: String):Future[Try[Seq[Group]]] = {
    val result:Future[Try[JsValue]] = getAPIResult(token, "https://myapi.com/screen_name=" + username)
    result.map( x => convertFromJsValueToObject(x))
  }

  def getSubscriptions(token: String, username: String):Future[Try[Seq[Group]]] = {...} //same as above

  private def getAPIResult(token: String, apiCall: String):Future[Try[JsValue]] = {
    WS.url(apiCall)
    .withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + token))
    .get().map(response =>
       response.status match {
       case 200 => Success(Json.parse(response.body))
       case _ => Failure(new RuntimeException("Web service call failed: " + response.body))
    })
  }

  private def convertFromJsValueToObject(json: Try[JsValue]): Try[Seq[Group]] = {
    json match {
      case Success(v) => {
        Success(v.as[Seq[Group]])
      }
      case Failure(t) => Failure(t)
      }
  }
```

and I have a third function like this:

```
def getAllListsAndSubscriptions(token: String, username: String):Future[Try[Seq[Group]]] = {...}
```

Which is supposed to concatenate the two `Seq` collections of `Group` objects together and return them as per the type signature. I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this though, as the types are so deeply nested.

Have I written my code badly or is there a way to do this? I'd appreciate an explanation as well, so that next time I get stuck on something like this I won't need to ask for help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems unnecessary to have a `Try` within a `Future`, since both capture the idea of an operation that can fail. If you're stuck would think you could squash those:

```
def getAllListsAndSubscriptions(token: String, username: String): Future[Try[Seq[Group]] =
  for {
    lists <- getLists(token, username).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
    subscriptions <- getSubscriptions(token, username).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
  } yield { lists ++ subscriptions }
```

Alternatively:

```
def getAllListsAndSubscriptions(token: String, username: String): Future[Try[Seq[Group]] =
  val lists = getLists(token, username).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
  val subscriptions = getSubscriptions(token, username)).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
  Future.reduce(Seq(lists, subscriptions))( _ ++ _)
```

But ideally, `Future[Try[_]]` never escapes those functions in the first place.

Comment: Read [this](http://mandubian.com/2013/02/22/scala-future-fatal-exception/) how `Future`s hide fatal exception

Comment: I don't understand the line 'Future.fromTry' - also, I can't get rid of the Try, I need it to for some specific error handling

Comment: @goral Good to know. But from the text, it sounds like it was intended to be fixed post-2.10.0. Do you know whether this is still a problem in 2.11.x?

Comment: @cm22 Notwithstanding @goral's point about some issues with this, but `Future` has 2 states, "successful" and "failed". The "failed" state contains an `Exception`. So wrapping a `Try` with a `Future` is kind of like wrapping a `Try` with another `Try`. If something fails in your functions, better to use a failed `Future` than a `Failed` within a successful `Future`. `Future.fromTry` "upgrades" a `Try` to a `Future`, and the `flatMap` causes the inner `Future` to replace the outer one, removing the extra layer. After that, you just have `Future[Seq[Group]]`, which is more natural to work with.

Comment: I'm using scala 2.10, do I need to implement this fromTry function? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: @cm22 If it's not in 2.10, you could reimplement  it with a pattern match on the `Try`: `try match { case Success(value) => Future.successful(value); case Failure(exception) => Future.failed(exception) }`